# Recommended v2 resource for the Activation Process in Ninject

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

Have been reading the documentation on Ninject and the Activation Process was changed in v2 and there is no supporting documentation at present.  Can someone suggest a good resource?

Answer (score 1):

I've gained a lot of insight by browsing the [source code](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/tree/master/src) on GitHub, in particular the [unit tests](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/tree/master/src/Ninject.Test/Unit) covering the aspect you're interested in.

Often times you'll see similarities in the scenarios covered by whatever wiki documentation exists and the unit tests there - not sure which is the chicken and which is the egg, but it's there.

Also, browsing questions ***answered*** by [Remo Gloor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448580/remo-gloor), [Ruben Bartelink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11635/ruben-bartelink) and [Ian Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122096/ian-davis?tab=answers&sort=votes), filtered by any of the Ninject-related tags has been very helpful for me.

Can you specify a particular scenario in the activation process change that you're interested?  You're more likely to get a focused answer to a question like that, which could help to reach broader understanding of what's changed...